# Terraform - data depends-on data

Tags: json, terraform

I am using data external and data local_file in my terraform code. 
data external executes a script and create a json file. Now my data local_file has to read the json file.

```
data "external" "example" {
   program = ["python", "XXXXX.py", "${var.fileName}"]
}

data "local_file" "dashboard" {
    filename = "${path.module}/dashboardData.json"
}
```

Here data local_file is dependent on data external for the json file.

Is there a work aroud ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your external data source outputs the filename you could use Terraform's interpolation to force a dependency between the 2 data sources.

So assuming the output of `python XXXXX.py fileName` gives `{"filename": "dashboardData.json"}` or similar then you could just use something like this:

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = ["python", "XXXXX.py", "${var.fileName}"]
}

data "local_file" "dashboard" {
  filename = "${path.module}/${data.external.example.result.filename}"
}
```

Because the `local_file` data source now refers to the `external` data source it will force Terraform to wait for the `external` data source to complete.

An alternative is to set an explicit dependency between them by using `depends_on`:

```
data "external" "example" {
  program = ["python", "XXXXX.py", "${var.fileName}"]
}

data "local_file" "dashboard" {
  filename   = "${path.module}/dashboardData.json"
  depends_on = [data.external.example]
}
```

Comment: Out of two the first one worked as expected. The second one is throwing some error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The second form should be `depends_on = [data.external.example]`  the error was `A static list expression is required.`, which tells that you need a LIST  Ref. https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#depends_on-explicit-resource-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force terraform to defer evaluating one value until after another is known, and there isn't an existing data source that covers your use case, you can use `null_data_source` as a stand-in.

```
data "null_data_source" "dashboard_file" {
  depends_on = [ "data.external.example.result" ]
  inputs = {
    name = "${path.module}/dashboardData.json"
  }
}
```

When the dependencies are met, terraform will evaluate all the inputs of the null_data_source, do nothing, and then expose all the results as outputs.

Now, you can refer to `data.null_data_source.dashboard_file.outputs.name`, and terraform knows that it must first compute `data.external.example.result` before it's allowed to use that value.